# Intercepting Signals From Processes

Tags: c, ruby, linux, signals

How I would go about capturing/intercepting signals sent to another process from my own process? Willing to use C, Ruby, or any Linux package.

Comment: Is it something like strace (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) that you are looking for ?

Comment: I don't know exactly how you mean it. If you are sending the signals, you can just wrap kill (if you are in C) and count all the signals you are sending. If the signal is sent, you cannot intercept it in any way, it is passed to the OS. Edit: @ascobol: right, if he means to monitor it externally, you can use Strace, good point.

Comment: My intention is to create a process monitoring daemon that will allow admins to put it hooks for when a process is sent a signal. For example, if I send a `kill -QUIT worker_master`, I could implement a hook that watches my `worker_master` and gracefully shuts down any `worker_slaves`. After all the slaves are dead, then we would actually send the `QUIT` signal to the master process.

Comment: I am still a bit unclear. Are you going to write a new version of kill and replace the exiisting one? Are you intending to provide a 'signal handler' framework, and write all your managed programs, that will have this capability, around that? Or is this also for existing programs which you will not change?  AFAIK, if a kill sigal is sent, the target process needs to handle it, if it can't it dies. IIRC you should be able to detect the death though.

Comment: I'm trying to make a daemon that applies hooks for signals sent to processes and will work almost like a proxy for the signal. Instead of "Signal gets sent to process and process responds to signal", this will allow "Signal gets sent to process, signal gets intercepted by daemon, daemon finds the hooks for this specific signal, daemon runs all 'before' hooks for this signal, daemon sends the signal to the process, process responds to signal, daemon runs all 'after' hooks for this signal."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a library wrapper that will replace system [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)/[sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) calls to intercept setting of the signal handler and set your own handlers. On received signal, you can do your job and call user handler later. Use [LD_PRELOAD](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) to replace system `signal`/`sigaction` routines by your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `ptrace(2)` system call is what you want. From the manual: "While  being  traced,  the  child  will  stop  each  time a signal is delivered, even if the signal is being ignored.  (The exception is SIGKILL, which has its usual effect.)  The parent will be notified at its next wait(2) and may inspect and modify the child process while it is stopped.  The parent then causes the child to continue, optionally ignoring the delivered signal (or even delivering a different signal instead)."